# Fix ttk overwriting tkinter label and button font/style

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Based on [effbot.org's example](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-option-database.htm) the following code will set default styles:

```
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

root.option_add("*Font", "courier")
root.option_add("*Label.Font", "helvetica 20 bold")
root.option_add("*Background", "brown")
root.config(background="light blue")

Label(root, text="lbl").pack()
Button(root, text="bttn").pack()
Message(root, text="msg").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

which looks like this:

[image: correct look]

However, if you uncomment the second line, the result will be like this:

[image: wrong look]

Apparently, `tkinter.ttk` overwrites the font style of `Label` and `Button` with objects which ignore `root.option_add()`.

Knowing that I only need `Treeview` from `ttk`, I can simply change the second line to `from tkinter.ttk import Treeview` to avoid the issue. However, it would be useful to be in control of the situation rather than avoiding it.

How to change `Label` and `Button` fonts and styles after `from tkinter.ttk import *`?

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, tkinter.ttk overwrites the font style of Label and Button
>   with objects which ignore root.option_add().

The import doesn't overwrite the *style*, it overwrites the *widget*. When you do `Label(...)` or `Button(...)` you are getting a ttk widget rather than a tk widget since you imported that library last. ttk widgets don't honor all of the same options as tk widgets.

If you want to change the fonts and styles of ttk widgets, you must do so using the ttk styling mechanism. For more information see [Styles and Themes](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) on [tkdocs.com](http://tkdocs.com).

This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use wildcard imports -- it makes it hard to understand exactly which type of widget you're using or intending to use, and impossible to use both kinds in the same application.

The best way to import tkinter and tk is to import the module, and use the module name as a prefix. I recommend importing tkinter "as tk" so that the prefix is short:

```
# python 2.x
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

# python 3.x
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

You can then use tk widgets like this:

```
tk.Button(...)
tk.Label(...)
```

and ttk widgets like this:

```
ttk.Button(...)
ttk.Label(...)
ttk.Treeview(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead,
`import tkinter as tk`,
and use it this way:
`tk.Label` etc.